# How do you start and write a .xml page in PhpStorm

Tags: xml, ide, phpstorm

Pretty newbie question but ... how do you start/setup and write XML in PhpStorm?

I do get an area to write code in when I create a .xml file. It does the same when I try to import files from sublime.

[image]

Comment: It should open file on double click. If that doesn't happen, check Help > Show Log in Explorer > idea.log file for any errors.

Comment: i got 3 different idea.log files
idea.log
idea.log.2
idea.log.3

Comment: idea.log
ERROR - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - PhpStorm 2017.3.4

Comment: That's unfortunately is not enough. If you still see issues even after disabling 3rd-party plugins (such as Material Theme UI) then please contact tech support via https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731 and they will assist you with this issue.

Comment: thanks for the help it didn't work for me. so i just tried a complete reinstall and worked for me